# jQuery's dialog plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the point of storing the ui-dialog-title object in the uiDialogTitle variable, if the variable is never used anywhere in code?

```
        uiDialogTitle = $('<span></span>')
            .addClass('ui-dialog-title')
            .attr('id', titleId)
            .html(title)
            .prependTo(uiDialogTitlebar);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is never used, don't store the value into a variable.

```
$('<span></span>')
    .addClass('ui-dialog-title')
    .attr('id', titleId)
    .html(title)
    .prependTo(uiDialogTitlebar);
```

This will accomplish the same.